# Apache camel with external ActiveMQ broker

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am learning to use Apache Camel to solve a messaging problem. The following points explains the gist of the problem.

1. There is an external ActiveMQ broker which expects a message in JSON format and returns a response in JSON format.
2. The JSON message that is sent to the broker must be created during runtime, by getting a parameter from the user.
3. The returned response is returned to the user.

I am finding it difficult to follow the book examples and fit it to my problem. Please let me know how this can be solved using Apache Camel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

- use [camel-activemq](http://camel.apache.org/activemq.html) to connect to your ActiveMQ broker
- use [camel json marshalling](https://camel.apache.org/json.html) support to convert requests to this format...

just need to setup your `activemq` component like this

> ```
>   <bean id="activemq"
>         class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
>         <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://mybroker:61616"/>    
>   </bean>
> ```

then define routes to produce/consume from ActiveMQ queues, convert to/from JSON as needed...

for example...one route to take the client request, convert to JSON and send to a queue

> ```
> from("direct:clientRequest")
>     .marshal().json()
>     .to("activemq:firstQueue");
> ```

then another route to pickup from another queue and unmarshal from JSON and do something with it...

> ```
> from("activemq:otherQueue")
>     .unmarshal().json()
>     .to("<do something>");
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you also please tell how can I produce a java bean using "direct:clientRequest" which can be converted to JSON and used in the above suggested way?

Comment: you can use a ProducerTemplate to send a request to a route:  http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html